# Fortran90 Reading and filling in arrays from data file

Tags: multidimensional-array, fortran

I am supposed to read in this file and fill in the arrays from that data file. But every time i try to run it, i receive an error saying i have invalid memory. The file looks like this

```
4  
SanDiego  
0  
350  
900  
1100  
Phoenix  
350  
0  
560  
604  
Denver  
900  
560  
0  
389  
Dallas  
1100  
604  
389  
0
```

It is basically a traveling salesman algorithm that takes gives the best distance. Here is my whole code

```
Program P4

IMPLICIT NONE

!Variable Declarations
INTEGER :: count, i, j, ios, distance=0, permutations=0, best_distance
CHARACTER(50) :: filename
TYPE city
CHARACTER(20) :: name
END TYPE
TYPE(city), ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:) :: city_list
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE,  DIMENSION(:,:) :: d_table
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:) :: path, best_path

PRINT *, "Enter filename"
READ *, filename

!Open the file and read number of cities
OPEN(UNIT = 15, FILE = filename, FORM="FORMATTED", ACTION="READ", STATUS="OLD", IOSTAT=ios)
        IF(ios /= 0) THEN
                PRINT *, "ERROR, could not open file.", TRIM(filename), "Error code: ", ios
                STOP
        END IF

READ (UNIT=15, FMT=100) count
PRINT *, "Number of cities: ", count


!Allocate memory for all needed arrays
ALLOCATE(city_list(1:count), d_table(1:count,1:count), best_path(1:count), path(1:count), STAT=ios)

        IF(ios /= 0) THEN
                PRINT *, "ERROR, could not allocate memory."
                STOP
        END IF

!Fill in arrays from data file



    DO i=1, count
        path(i) = i
        READ(UNIT=15, FMT=200) city_list(i)
                IF(ios < 0) THEN
                        EXIT
                END IF

         DO j=1, 4
                PRINT *, i, j, city_list(i)
                READ(UNIT=15, FMT=100) d_table(i,j)
         END DO
END DO





!Use recursion to find minimal distance
CALL permute(2, count)

!Print formatted output
PRINT *
DO i=1, count
        PRINT *, path(i)
END DO
DO i=1, count
        PRINT *, (city_list(i))
END DO

DO i=1, count
        DO j=1, count
                PRINT *, d_table(i,j)
        END DO
END DO


100 FORMAT (I6)
200 FORMAT (A)


CONTAINS
!Permute function
RECURSIVE SUBROUTINE permute(first, last)
!Declare intent of parameter variables
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: first, last
INTEGER :: i, temp
        IF(first == last) THEN
                distance = d_table(1,path(2))
                PRINT *, city_list(1)%name, city_list(path(2))%name, " ", d_table(1, path(2))
       DO i=2, last-1
                distance = distance + d_table(path(i),path(i+1))
                print *, city_list(path(i))%name, " ", city_list(path(i+1))%name,  d_table(path(i),path(i+1))
 END DO
            distance = distance + d_table(path(last),path(1))
            PRINT *, city_list(path(last))%name," ",city_list(path(1))%name, d_table(path(last),path(1))
            PRINT *, "Distance is ",distance
            PRINT *
            permutations = permutations + 1
            IF(distance < best_distance) THEN
                best_distance = distance
                DO i=2, count
                    best_path(i) = path(i)
                END DO
            END IF

        ELSE
            DO i=first, last
                temp = path(first)
                path(first) = path(i)
                path(i) = temp

                call permute(first+1,last)

                temp = path(first)
                path(first) = path(i)
                path(i) = temp
            END DO
        END IF
END SUBROUTINE permute

END PROGRAM P4
```

And i am no longer gettting an error message and able to run the program, but it its not running properly, it is supposed to out put this

```
Number of cities: 4
28 San Diego Phoenix 350
29 Phoenix Denver 560
30 Denver Dallas 389
31 Dallas San Diego 1100
32 Distance is 2399
33
34 San Diego Phoenix 350
35 Phoenix Dallas 604
36 Dallas Denver 389
37 Denver San Diego 900
38 Distance is 2243
39
40 San Diego Denver 900
41 Denver Phoenix 560
42 Phoenix Dallas 604
43 Dallas San Diego 1100
44 Distance is 3164
45
46 San Diego Denver 900
47 Denver Dallas 389
48 Dallas Phoenix 604
49 Phoenix San Diego 350
50 Distance is 2243
51
52 San Diego Dallas 1100
53 Dallas Denver 389
54 Denver Phoenix 560
55 Phoenix San Diego 350
56 Distance is 2399
57
58 San Diego Dallas 1100
59 Dallas Phoenix 604
60 Phoenix Denver 560
61 Denver San Diego 900
62 Distance is 3164
63
64
65 San Diego to Phoenix -- 350 miles
66 Phoenix to Dallas -- 604 miles
67 Dallas to Denver -- 389 miles
68 Denver to San Diego -- 900 miles
69
70 Best distance is: 2243
71 Number of permutations: 6
```

But instead it out puts this

```
Enter filename
data.txt
 Number of cities:            4
           1           1 SanDiego
           1           2 SanDiego
           1           3 SanDiego
           1           4 SanDiego
           2           1 Phoenix
           2           2 Phoenix
           2           3 Phoenix
           2           4 Phoenix
           3           1 Denver
           3           2 Denver
           3           3 Denver
           3           4 Denver
           4           1 Dallas
           4           2 Dallas
           4           3 Dallas
           4           4 Dallas
 SanDiego            Phoenix                      1100
 Phoenix              Denver                       604
 Denver               Dallas                       389
 Dallas               SanDiego                       0
 Distance is         2093

 SanDiego            Phoenix                      1100
 Phoenix              Dallas                       604
 Dallas               Denver                         0
 Denver               SanDiego                     389
 Distance is         2093

 SanDiego            Denver                       1100
 Denver               Phoenix                      389
 Phoenix              Dallas                       604
 Dallas               SanDiego                       0
 Distance is         2093

 SanDiego            Denver                       1100
 Denver               Dallas                       389
 Dallas               Phoenix                        0
 Phoenix              SanDiego                     604
 Distance is         2093

 SanDiego            Dallas                       1100
 Dallas               Denver                         0
 Denver               Phoenix                      389
 Phoenix              SanDiego                     604
 Distance is         2093

 SanDiego            Dallas                       1100
 Dallas               Phoenix                        0
 Phoenix              Denver                       604
 Denver               SanDiego                     389
 Distance is         2093


           1
           2
           3
           4
 SanDiego
 Phoenix
 Denver
 Dallas
        1100
        1100
        1100
        1100
         604
         604
         604
         604
         389
         389
         389
         389
           0
           0
           0
           0
```

Comment: welcome , please share your code , otherwise people will downvote your question

Comment: Please don't add your code as an image and give a complete  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. We really need a reasonably complete piece of code **as text**. Do not use pictures, copy and paste your code as text. It is extremely important and completely necessary. Do not forget te declare all your variables and use `implicit none`. Also, copy and paste the **exact error message** as text.

Comment: @Al-Amin While avoiding being downvoted may motivate people to supply their code, the real reason is that almost always without a complete code it is just impossible to answer the question!

Comment: I have edited the post, pls help and thank you

Comment: When line 39 is `READ (UNIT=15, FMT=100, IOSTAT=ios) city_list(i)` why use format=100 as this is an integer format, probably you wanted to use format=200.

Comment: i changed that to 200 and still got the same error

Comment: Compile wit debug options and with checking options (please check  the options of your compiler)

Comment: i compile using f95 -o p4 p4.f95

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first open the file, the READ command reads the first line. If you call READ again, you will read line two.

I think that this error comes because you are trying to READ the first line (for the second time) but you are actually reading the second line that is a STRING.

You have two options to fix the error in line 39 (READ statement):

1. Call the OPEN statement (before the line 39) for a second time in order to READ the first line
2. Or delete the READ statement because you have already read "count" before (best option in my opinion)

**Update:For segmentation fault error**
I maid the following changes:

1. Comment line 39 (to solve the first problem)
2. In line 42: `FMT=200`
3. In line 46: `DO j=1, 4` (because between the cities names there are only 4 numbers)

The following code worked for me:

```
Program P4

IMPLICIT NONE

!Variable Declarations
INTEGER :: count, i, j, ios, distance=0, permutations=0, best_distance
CHARACTER(50) :: filename
TYPE city
CHARACTER(20) :: name
END TYPE
TYPE(city), ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:) :: city_list
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE,  DIMENSION(:,:) :: d_table
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:) :: path, best_path

PRINT *, "Enter filename"
READ *, filename

!Open the file and read number of cities
OPEN(UNIT = 15, FILE = filename, FORM="FORMATTED", ACTION="READ", STATUS="OLD", IOSTAT=ios)
        IF(ios /= 0) THEN
                PRINT *, "ERROR, could not open file.", TRIM(filename), "Error code: ", ios
                STOP
        END IF

READ (UNIT=15, FMT=100) count
PRINT *, "Number of cities: ", count


!Allocate memory for all needed arrays
ALLOCATE(city_list(1:count), d_table(1:count,1:count), best_path(1:count), path(1:count), STAT=ios)

        IF(ios /= 0) THEN
                PRINT *, "ERROR, could not allocate memory."
                STOP
        END IF

!Fill in arrays from data file

!READ (UNIT=15, FMT=100) count
DO i=1, count
        path(i-1) = i
READ (UNIT=15, FMT=200, IOSTAT=ios) city_list(i)
        IF(ios < 0) THEN
                EXIT
        END IF
DO j=1, 4
    print*,i,j,city_list(i)
 READ (UNIT=15, FMT=100) d_table(i,j)
END DO
END DO



!Use recursion to find minimal distance
CALL permute(2, count)

!Print formatted output
PRINT *
DO i=1, count
        PRINT *, path(i)
END DO
DO i=1, count
        PRINT *, (city_list(i))
END DO

DO i=1, count
        DO j=1, count
                PRINT *, d_table(i,j)
        END DO
END DO


100 FORMAT (I6)
200 FORMAT (A)


CONTAINS
!Permute function
RECURSIVE SUBROUTINE permute(first, last)
!Declare intent of parameter variables
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: first, last
INTEGER :: i, temp
        IF(first == last) THEN
                distance = d_table(1,path(2))
                PRINT *, city_list(1)%name, city_list(path(2))%name, " ", d_table(1, path(2))
       DO i=2, last-1
                distance = distance + d_table(path(i),path(i+1))
                print *, city_list(path(i))%name, " ", city_list(path(i+1))%name,  d_table(path(i),path(i+1))
 END DO
            distance = distance + d_table(path(last),path(1))
            PRINT *, city_list(path(last))%name," ",city_list(path(1))%name, d_table(path(last),path(1))
            PRINT *, "Distance is ",distance
            PRINT *
            permutations = permutations + 1
            IF(distance < best_distance) THEN
                best_distance = distance
                DO i=2, count
                    best_path(i) = path(i)
                END DO
            END IF

        ELSE
            DO i=first, last
                temp = path(first)
                path(first) = path(i)
                path(i) = temp

                call permute(first+1,last)

                temp = path(first)
                path(first) = path(i)
                path(i) = temp
            END DO
        END IF
END SUBROUTINE permute

END PROGRAM P4
```

Comment: Repeating `open` won't change the position of the file (unless the connection is closed first), but a `rewind` may.

Comment: Why don't you delete/comment the READ on line 39? It is not necessary

Comment: Ive done that and have updated my code, but now i am receiving a segmentation fault. I will update the post as shown

Comment: Thank you! Ive updated my code and it is not working properly the way its suppposed to work. Please help

Comment: Please, if this answer solved the errors in the question, close this thread and open another one with the new problems. Thank you!